# Как изолировать составные части proxy_cache_key?

Tags: nginx

Например:

```
proxy_cache_key $request_uri$cookie_foo

$request_uri: /
$cookie_foo: foo
=> /foo

$request_uri: /foo
$cookie_foo: ''
=> /foo
```

В итоге получаем два одинаковых ключа на совершенно разные запросы. Задача в том чтобы на 100% изолировать составные части ключа чтобы вообще не думать о том, что они могут перемешаться.

Использование пробела (которые кстати говоря вырезаются при пустых значениях, что ещё больше всё запутывает), другого символа или строки в качестве разделителя на 100% такие совпадения не исключают. Только если не генерировать такую boundary при каждом запросе и убеждаться в её отсутствии в каждой составной части ключа...

Comment: `"${request_uri}:::${cookie_foo}"`

Comment: @norbornen Ну т.е. просто использование в качестве разделителя три двоеточия?

Comment: Что угодно, что вряд ли встретится в ваших урлах и куках.

Comment: @MaximYaskov, возьми встроенный perl или nginScript, если тебе для формирования ключа нужен программизм. Если же для решения твоей задачи это оверхед то достаточно придумать разделитель, смысл которого хорошо раскрыл Алексей Тен. Можешь писать хоть `req=${request_uri}, cookie=${cookie_foo}`

Comment: Думаю в качестве разделителя можно довольно безопасно использовать символ `|`. На самом деле разделитель может присутствовать в составных элементах ключа, но во избежание генерации одинаковых ключей на разные запросы, разделители не должны встречаться в произвольном количестве на концах как минимум двух соседних элементов ключа (или элементах между которыми возможны одни только пустые значения).